# Variable as array/object key in Ansible

Tags: arrays, variables, yaml, ansible

I am writing a playbook that creates a network with a name I assign. Later on in the playbook I need to access the IP that is assigned by this network task, so I get it from the hostvars. So for example it if I was calling the network 'my_website' the value I would be targeting in hostvars would be

```
server: "{{hostvars.localhost.rax_nfs.results[0].success[0].rax_addresses.my_website[0].addr}}"
```

This is fine, but I want to name the network based on the contents of a variable passed in by a var file to make it reusable across multiple setups, and then still be able to get that IP back, so

```
network_label: "{{ my_website }}"
server: "{{hostvars.localhost.rax_nfs.results[0].success[0].rax_addresses.network_label[0].addr}}"
```

Obviously this doesn't work as it just assigns a string. How do I use network_label as the key inside another variable? Like in php something like

$array[$variable], or $object->$variable

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the playbook looks like but does accessing the IP based on the gathered facts not work in your context? Example:  {{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}

Alternatively on the task that creates the network you could register that as a variable for later access using that variable name. 
You can also access elements of an array in a variable: {{ var_name[0] }}

Comment: I'll post an example of what I use and what I get back. 

To me though, this hints at a larger restriction - I can't use variables to target other variables?